# Angular.js jQuery passthrough accessing elements

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angular-ui

Is there a way to access another element (& onclick) with jQuery passthrough? For example, to achieve the below:

```
<div id="that"></div>
<a ui-jq="slideUp">slide Up #that</a>
```

From the [docs](http://angular-ui.github.com/) it isn't clear :)

Comment: Sorry, which docs are you referring to? Angular docs, AngularUI docs, or jQuery docs? From the question it isn't clear :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ui-jq` is not the answer to everything, especially for what you're trying to do.

Instead, try using `ui-show` and related directives alongside some custom CSS. Or if you're using bootstrap, check out the code for the [collapse directive](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/#/collapse).

Overall, you're better off using Angular to simply toggle a class and handling the sliding and transitions that way. Or you can try creating a custom directive if CSS transitions won't cut it.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you! I should have looked at the docs more thoroughly :?